# Search certain word in title or as a tag

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, search, title

I'd like to get a list of all questions that have "z3" (or any other word) in the title or are tagged with it, e.g. something like

```
title:z3 OR [z3]
```

This doesn't work, however, as the system searches for "z3 or" in the title. Without "OR" the default behaviour seems to be to search for questions tagged with "z3" AND having "z3" in the title.

Searching with Google does not look like a good alternative because it lists way more questions than desired.

<sup>P.S. At the time of writing, the "z3" tag doesn't yet exists</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use `[z3] or title:z3`.

It worked for me, I think.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bz3%5D+or+title%3Az3

Comment: That doesn't work at all. I just clicked on your link and got 0 results. After removing `or title:z3` I got 396 results.

Answer (score -1):

Do two separate searches. That is, first do a search for all questions having "z3" in the title, than do a search for all the questions tagged with z3

Comment: That sounds as if it results in two unrelated searches. I need to link to the search results for `title:z3 OR [z3]`, I don't want to provide two different links.

Answer (score -1):

Do a search for title:z3, then add the [z3] tag to any of the question that don't have it that should.

Then just do a search for the tag.

(E.g. fix the problem for everyone)

Comment: That would require me to search for new entries and to tag them accordingly in regular intervals. Well, better than nothing, I guess.